# [localhost:15005]: java.net.BindException: Permission denied

Tags: tomcat, openshift

I created `DIY` on `OpenShift`, installed `Tomcat` and when I am starting it it shows:

[image]

Below you can see fragments from `server.xml` file:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Server port to -1 like this: `<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">` as it is done in the official tomcat cartridges shown here: https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews/usr/versions/2.0/configuration/server.xml#L22

When you specify the Server port it is trying to bind to localhost, which is not allowed.

Comment: It eliminated the error. I got another error though: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/temp]]` I read some threads on stackoverflow regarding the error, but not sure how to fix it still on openshift.